# Azure vm quick-start isn't linking the created IP address to the vm

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

When I use the vm quick-start to spin up a new Linux vm, it shows the public ip address being provisioned however it is not linked to the vm itself. If I go into the portal, I can see that the VM and IP exist, but must manually allow the IP to link to the VM. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the 0.9.15 CLI version had this as a known bug. 0.9.16 and forward have fixed this issue, if you see the same one update the CLI and you should be good.